# Couchbase Lite to CouchDB Replication - No Data

Tags: android, couchdb, replication, couchbase-lite

I'm currently using CouchbaseLite on and Android app and I just started using the replication feature to synce to a couchdb database(Which I'm new to).

Heres the problem I've followed all the steps outlined[here](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/replication/index.html)

My Replication object sends me an idle status. But I have no data in the specific couchdb database I pointed it to. Could there be anything I'm missing?

```
URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.100:5984/data/");
            push = database.createPushReplication(url);
            pull = database.createPullReplication(url);
            pull.setContinuous(true);
            push.setContinuous(true);
            BasicAuthenticator authenticator = new BasicAuthenticator("olabode", "couch");
            pull.setAuthenticator(authenticator);
            push.setAuthenticator(authenticator);

            pull.addChangeListener(this);
            push.addChangeListener(this);

            push.setFilter("addStoreNameFilter");
            pull.setFilter("pullCurrentStoreFilter");

            // Start
            push.start();
            pull.start();

database.setFilter("addStoreNameFilter", new ReplicationFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean filter(SavedRevision savedRevision, Map<String, Object> map) {
            map.put(Dao.STORE_ID, storeId);
            return true;
        }
    });

    database.setFilter("pullCurrentStoreFilter", new ReplicationFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean filter(SavedRevision savedRevision, Map<String, Object> map) {
            String currentStoreId = (String) map.get(Dao.STORE_ID);
            if (currentStoreId == storeId)
                return true;

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You use continuous replication.

```
pull.setContinuous(true);
push.setContinuous(true);
```

In this case, having `Idle` status is fine.

> Idle: Indicates that a continuous replication has "caught up" and transferred all documents, but is monitoring the source database for future changes.

[Observing and monitoring replications](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/replication/index.html#observing)